# How many nand gates does a computer actually need to operate?

Tags: hardware, boolean-logic, cpu-architecture

At first I was thinking that logic gates were much smaller than they actually are:

https://www.google.com/search?q=nand+gates#q=nand+gates&tbm=shop

So my question is, how many logic gates (similar to the one above) does a computer actually need to operate?  Since this number must be somewhat small due to size limitations (there clearly cannot be millions of these in a computer), how is it that the computer can work with such a small number of these gates?

Comment: CPUs commonly have **billions** of transistors in them (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count) — each logic gate is often one or a small number of transistors.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite so for each transistor / small group of transistors, there may be a logic gate solely dedicated to them?

Comment: http://www.cs.bu.edu/~best/courses/modules/Transistors2Gates/ each logic gate is made up of a small number of transistors, so if there are billions of transistors in the CPU, there must also be billions of logic gates.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-large-scale_integration

Comment: A decent fraction of the transistors in a modern CPU are spent on memory arrays, used as cache (L1, L2, and L3, and also the TLBs, and various buffers).  Each bit of storage (an SRAM cell) might be 4 or 6 transistors, or maybe even more.  (Using more transistors can actually save power, by letting it run without errors at a lower voltage).  But the rest of the transistors are part of logic circuits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just shop for nand gates, those are ones used for hobbies or other markets, nand gates are in your processor in your computer, and they're not individual component but directly lithographied on the die, they are a few nanometers in size and there are billons of them on a modern processor.